# Delete tasks based on duration and indention

Tags: vba, ms-project

My work generates pretty large (2k+ tasks) MS project files, however, a lot of the tasks are "dummy tasks" and are not needed, and it falls upon me and others to remove them. We remove the tasks that are "bottom level" meaning that they have no subtasks, and that are of a specific length, let's say 1000 days.

So I am looking for a macro that, if possible, loops through the tasks, and deletes all tasks that have no subtasks and have duration 1000 days.

I have no experience working with MS project, and very limited experience working with VBA and programming in general. I have googled a fair bit, but have made no progress.

Thanks in advance. Oscar

Code I've got at the moment:

```
Sub DeleteMsProjectTask()
Dim proj As Project
Dim t As Task
Set proj = ActiveProject

Do While proj.Tasks.Count > 0
    For Each t In proj.Tasks
        If Not (t.Summary) Then
            t.Delete
        End If
    Next t
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you share the code you already have and show where it doesn't do what you want it to do?

Comment: Yes, edited the original post

Comment: And doens't it delete anything? Or only some of the tasks? And if you go through the code line by line, does it skip some of it?

Comment: This deletes all the tasks. I'm not sure how to properly add the desired checks (if even possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add some elements to your if-statement.

Use something like `If t.OutlineChildren.count = 0 and t.Duration > 480000`

The `Duration` property is apparently counted in minutes of the working day, so you have to find out which number suits you there.

Comment: It works! Fantastic work Alex. Thank you so much, you've helped me save many hours. Dank u zeer!!